# Editing end of contenteditable when last child is not editable

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div which can contain text and non-editable elements.

Normally you can click after the content and then start editing the content however if the last element in the div is non-editable this is not possible, you cant just click in the whitespace and start typing.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/174dersh/1/

```
    <div contenteditable="true">
        <span contenteditable="false">Read only</span>
        Not Read Only
    </div>
    
    <div contenteditable="true">
      <span contenteditable="false">Read only</span>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to address this?

Comment: (For anyone wondering - this appears to be a Firefox issue; in a Chromium-based browser on Mac I can click and type after the second "Read only" fine in the given jsfiddle.)

Comment: @CBroe thanks, looks like that is the case on Windows as well.